# Keep removing last-child of a <ul> based on width?

Tags: html, css

I have this layout and I'd like to keep removing the last-child of the list (shrink) the lower the resolution is. The code is exactly my implementation:

```css
p > span {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.layout1 {
  width: 1170px;
  list-style: none;
  background: gray;
  position: relative;
}

.layout1 > li {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 24%;
  margin-right: 1%;
  height: 100px;
  background: #dbca7f;
}

.layout1 > li:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}

/* 
/* This is what I'd like to do for about 3 times, keep cutting, ignore the (-justToMakeItNotWork, the code would otherwise work without it. */

@media screen and (max-width: 990px) {
  .layout1(-justToMakeItNotWork) > li:last-child {
    display: none;
  }
}

/* And again */

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .layout1(-justToMakeItNotWork) > li:last-child {
    display: none;
  }
}

/* And again, probably */
```

```html
<!-- There are other bootstrap classes added, but only col-XX-NN, irrelevant to the issue. -->
<p> This is the full view </p>
<ul class="layout1 col-md-12">
  <li class="post col-md-3">
  <li class="post col-md-3">
  <li class="post col-md-3">
  <li class="post col-md-3">
</ul>

<p> Let's assume that we're now unde 768px, <span> I'd like to now cut the number of posts show to 3</span>, like this: </p>

<ul class="layout1 col-md-12">
  <li class="post col-md-3">
  <li class="post col-md-3">
  <li class="post col-md-3">
</ul>

<p> That would work fine with just a rule, okay, but now let's say my screen got down-graded to ~468px. <span>I'd like to do it again and cut my posts to just 2: </span></p>

<ul class="layout1 col-md-12">
  <li class="post col-md-3">
  <li class="post col-md-3">
</ul>
```

Which translates to, on full view:

[image: My Full Layout]

I'd like to achieve, on lower screens, something like this:

[image: The lower resolution example.]

And 2 columns / posts on < 468px respectively.

The table of values:

```
1170px - 4 columns.
990px - 4 columns.
768px - 3 columns.
468px - 2 columns.
```

Unfortunately, adding `@media-queries` to keep removing the last-child doesn't work after the first `last-child` being removed. How can I fix this?

Additionally, I can't add a rule to remove the last 2-childs, because the higher-resolution rule already has trimmed down 1 post, as such, I'll be left with just one post.

Comment: Do you actually want to *remove* the last column, or do you want it to go onto the next line?

Comment: Are you using Bootstrap? If so you could easily use the responsive classes (`.hidden-md`, `.hidden-sm`) to hide the items you want to hide at certain resolutions. See docs [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#responsive-utilities)

Comment: @Jonathan Remove.

Comment: @zgood I'll look into that. This is a WordPress theme, though, the content is dynamic, but perhaps I can wrap the last 2 divs up! :) // Edit: Okay, it works, I'd still like a non-bootstrap fix, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`nth-last-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-last-child) in a similar manner to `nth-child`

```
@media screen and (max-width: 990px) {
  .layout1 > li:nth-last-child(1) {
    display: none;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .layout1 > li:nth-last-child(2) {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```css
p > span {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.layout1 {
  list-style: none;
  background: gray;
  position: relative;
}

.layout1 > li {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 24%;
  margin-right: 1%;
  height: 100px;
  background: #dbca7f;
}

.layout1 > li:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}

/* 
/* This is what I'd like to do for about 3 times, keep cutting, ignore the (-justToMakeItNotWork, the code would otherwise work without it. */

@media screen and (max-width: 990px) {
  .layout1 > li:nth-last-child(1) {
    display: none;
  }
}

/* And again */

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .layout1 > li:nth-last-child(2) {
    display: none;
  }
}

/* And again, probably */
```

```html
<!-- There are other bootstrap classes added, but only col-XX-NN, irrelevant to the issue. -->
<p> This is the full view </p>
<ul class="layout1 col-md-12">
  <li class="post col-md-3">
  <li class="post col-md-3">
  <li class="post col-md-3">
  <li class="post col-md-3">
</ul>
```

Comment: @DanielMoss Don't forget to hit the grey checkmark beside his answer to mark it as solved. :)

Answer (score 1):

You could use `:nth-last-child(-n+2)` to get the last 2 children:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .layout1(-justToMakeItNotWork) > li:nth-last-child(-n+2) {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `:nth-child(n+x)` to target elements. Like "select all but the first x elements".

```
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .layout1 > li:nth-child(n+3) {
    display: none;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 468px) {
  .layout1 > li:nth-child(n+2) {
    display: none;
  }
}
```